# test google analytics (GA4) gtag.js from localhost

Tags: firefox, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I am trying to send some events to google analytics using gtag.js. I have added this code to the head section of the html:


window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

```
        gtag('config', 'MEASUREMENT_ID', {
            'cookie_flags': 'SameSite=None;Secure',
            'cookie_domain': 'https://subdomain2.subdomain1.force.com',
        });
    </script>
```

And in the code I am calling this function:

```
  gtag("event", "dummy_test", {
    event_category: "test_category",
    event_label: "test_label",
    value: 96,
  });
```

But when the page loads, I am seeing this in the firefox (99.0.1) console:

Cookie “_ga_XXXXXXXXXX” has been rejected for invalid domain.

I am not seeing this message in the console if I am not setting the cookie_domain when I am configuring  gtag. Is there a way to test this without creating another stream url in the google analytics?

I have also tries setting the cookies like this, but the behavior is the same:

```
    gtag('set', {cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'});
    gtag('set', {'cookie_domain': 'https://subdomain2.subdomain1.force.com'});
    gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXX');
```

PS: I have disabled the adblocker and content tracking for localhost.